# I want to set shortcuts for "navigateBack" and "navigateForward" in Android studio on mac

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

workbench.action.navigateBack
workbench.action.navigateForward

My personal computer is a macbook.
I want to set the shortcut setting of the above command id in android studio, but I can't find it in key map.
It would be helpful if you could tell me the names of these commands, how to search them, or how to set them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Preferences` -> `Keymap`, here you can use search or manually open `Main menu` / `Navigate` folder. `Back` and `Forward` elements show default key shortcuts, also you can double click on the element and set your own shortcut, modify existed ones etc.

[image]

Comment: I could find it. Thank you for reply.